# Is XVFB (X virtual framebuffer) Open Source?

Tags: xvfb

Please tell me if XVFB is open source or not. If it is open source, please send me link for XVFB source package for Unix like operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, XVFB is part of x.org and is licensed under the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

As I said, it is part of the Xorg project and (AFAIK) there is no separate source code download for it. It shares lots of code with the Xorg display server. You can download all the Xorg source from [the mirrors listed here](http://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/Download/), but it's going to be quite a daunting task to understand it. There is some help in the [Xorg Developer Start](http://www.x.org/wiki/DeveloperStart/) section.